# How does VSCode [Remote Development] [Forward Port] work?

Tags: macos, docker, visual-studio-code, containers

When using VSCode [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) `Open Folder in Container` to develop in docker container in Mac, I can not find:

- Any info about the port by `docker inspect containerId`
- Any port config in Dockerfile

But I can still access the service in container from host browser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VS Code uses SSH Tunnel to connect to remote machine. The port forwarding is simply creating this tunnel.
You can do it without vscode with the command below if you have ssh client installed. You have to run this command from localhost shell prompt.
(I assumed we want to connect to port 8080 on remote-machine using localhost:8085)

`ssh -L 8085:remote-machine-ip:8080 remote-machine-ip`

Now, from your browser, if you go to http://localhost:8085 it will show content from remote-machine's 8080 service

Comment: VS Code seems to have some special magic. The ssh -L approach gives me `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

Comment: How does this work when using dev containers locally (no remote ssh)? As OP said, starting an app, that exposes a port, VSCode picks up that port and auto-forwards it to the host without Docker knowing about it.

Comment: >  VS Code uses SSH Tunnel to connect to remote machine