# How does VS Code automatically detect port allocated by the command and start port forwarding it when working remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I know that this question look similar to [VSCode [Remote Development] [Forward Port] work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701361/how-does-vscode-remote-development-forward-port-work) but it isn't.

When I launch a command which starts a web server on a random port (and prints out the url to access it),

VS Code auto detects the newly allocated port and starts port forwarding that port to my host machine.

How does this happen? Does VS Code check for newly allocated port by the current command ? If so, how does the shell script for this look like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been answered by VSCode developer on github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143958).

To summarize, VSCode will actively look into the proc file system ie. `/proc` directory and detect the port that was allocated and then start auto portforwarding it.

Comment: On Mac and Windows, it uses a different way: it looks at the terminal output for localhost urls. For example, if you run `echo https://localhost:8822/` in the terminal, it will auto forward port 8822 (this info was found in the github link provided in the answer, but the answer didn't mention it and seemed important)

Comment: It doesn't seem to respect the protocol, its trying `http://localhost` for me instead of `https`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `remote.autoForwardPorts` is set to `true`, it depends on the operating system that VS Code is running on.

On Windows and Mac remotes, it picks up from the terminal output (the `output` option under `remote.autoForwardPortsSource`):
[image: ports auto-forward source selection]

**Note:** on Windows and Mac remotes, selecting the `process` option has no effect and `output` will be used.

On other operating system remotes, if the `process` option is selected, VS Code watches for processes that start with a port included, and automatically forwards ports for those:
[image: ports auto-forwarded with process option]